# SDL Render and Texture, passing references

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl

I am trying to implement a Class window (with render and window), and a class Draw (of texture), and in order to draw i need to have a references to a render, but sins they are going to be generic classes, i can not marry my draw class to a single render, so i am trying to send a references to draw, of the render in window, so it can draw on the render...

i have something like this...

```
class SDLWindow{
        public:
            SDLWindow(std::string Title,int h=480, int w=640, int x=SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, int y=SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, Uint32 flag =SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
            void RendererOptions(Uint8,Uint8,Uint8,Uint8);
            void RendererClear();
            void RendererPresent();
            SDL_Renderer* ref2Window();
            ~SDLWindow();
        private:
            SDL_Window* DispWin;
            SDL_Renderer* DispRenderer;

    };
```

and i want this to be the function that helps me give a references of the render

```
SDL_Renderer* SDLWindow::ref2Window(){
    return DispRenderer;
}
```

this is the draw class

```
class SimpleDrawText{
    public:
        SimpleDrawText(std::string file,SDL_Renderer& ref, int w=100,int h=100, int x=0, int y=0);
        void Draw(SDL_Renderer& ref);
    protected:

    private:
        SDL_Texture* drawTexture; // the new SDL_Texture variable
        SDL_Rect source; // the first rectangle
        SDL_Rect destination; // another rectangle

        int posx;
        int posy;
        int height;
        int width;
};
```

and i am i get the references something like this

```
void SimpleDrawText::Draw(SDL_Renderer& ref){
    SDL_RenderCopy(&ref, drawTexture, &source, &destination);
}
```

i am sure, there is something very basic, of pointers and references, but i just can't figure out right now... any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
void SimpleDrawText::Draw(SDL_Renderer* ref){
    SDL_RenderCopy(ref, drawTexture, &source, &destination);
}
```

This is what you want to do i believe. Hope it helps.